# WiFi toggled when lid is opened, ignoring settings

Tags: linux, wifi, kde, manjaro, laptop

WiFi is toggled whenever I’m opening the lid of my laptop. I'm using Manjaro KDE. Setting “Do Nothing” in the Energy Saving settings doesn’t help. It’s happening on both AC power and battery. Bluetooth is unaffected.

Here's output of `journalctl` around a lid open event.

```
Feb 13 01:54:17 sintan-pc systemd-logind[11642]: Lid opened.
Feb 13 01:54:17 sintan-pc avahi-daemon[453]: Got SIGHUP, reloading.
Feb 13 01:54:17 sintan-pc avahi-daemon[453]: No service file found in /etc/avahi/services.
Feb 13 01:54:17 sintan-pc dhcpcd[467]: wlo1: old hardware address: a0:af:bd:4f:d8:5f
Feb 13 01:54:17 sintan-pc dhcpcd[467]: wlo1: new hardware address: ea:52:e1:b6:0e:ef
Feb 13 01:54:17 sintan-pc plasmashell[1065]: file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.plasma.notifications/contents/ui/NotificationPopup.qml:116:15: QML QQuickItem: Binding loop detected f>
Feb 13 01:54:17 sintan-pc wpa_supplicant[608]: nl80211: deinit ifname=wlo1 disabled_11b_rates=0
```

Also, some other info about my system.

```
systemd-inhibit --list

WHO            UID  USER   PID  COMM            WHAT                                                                       WHY                                                        MODE 
ModemManager   0    root   527  ModemManager    sleep                                                                      ModemManager needs to reset devices                        delay
NetworkManager 0    root   474  NetworkManager  sleep                                                                      NetworkManager needs to turn off networks                  delay
UPower         0    root   875  upowerd         sleep                                                                      Pause device polling                                       delay
Discord        1000 sintan 3413 Discord         sleep                                                                      Application cleanup before suspend                         delay
PowerDevil     1000 sintan 1140 org_kde_powerde handle-power-key:handle-suspend-key:handle-hibernate-key:handle-lid-switch KDE handles power events                                   block
Screen Locker  1000 sintan 1083 ksmserver       sleep                                                                      Ensuring that the screen gets locked before going to sleep delay

6 inhibitors listed.
```

My `systemd` version is `247.2-1`.

```
inxi -Fazy

System:
  Kernel: 5.10.7-3-MANJARO x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 10.2.1 
  parameters: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.10-x86_64 
  root=UUID=fe64fafd-1c2a-4b55-846f-c264196ff166 rw nomce "acpi_osi=Windows 
  2018" quiet resume=UUID=4517ac81-4ac6-42a0-8e7a-a5870b5f98df 
  Desktop: KDE Plasma 5.20.5 tk: Qt 5.15.2 wm: kwin_x11 dm: GDM 3.38.2.1, SDDM 
  Distro: Manjaro Linux 
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: HP product: HP Pavilion Laptop 14-bf1xx 
  v: Type1ProductConfigId serial: <filter> Chassis: type: 10 serial: <filter> 
  Mobo: HP model: 83CE v: 59.38 serial: <filter> UEFI: Insyde v: F.31 
  date: 10/30/2017 
Battery:
  ID-1: BAT1 charge: 35.3 Wh condition: 42.3/42.3 Wh (100%) volts: 13.1/11.6 
  model: Hewlett-Packard PABAS0241231 type: Li-ion serial: <filter> 
  status: Charging 
CPU:
  Info: Quad Core model: Intel Core i7-8550U bits: 64 type: MT MCP 
  arch: Kaby Lake note: check family: 6 model-id: 8E (142) stepping: A (10) 
  microcode: E0 L2 cache: 8 MiB 
  flags: avx avx2 lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 bogomips: 32012 
  Speed: 700 MHz min/max: 400/1800 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 700 2: 700 3: 700 
  4: 700 5: 700 6: 700 7: 700 8: 700 
  Vulnerabilities: Type: itlb_multihit status: KVM: VMX unsupported 
  Type: l1tf mitigation: PTE Inversion 
  Type: mds mitigation: Clear CPU buffers; SMT vulnerable 
  Type: meltdown mitigation: PTI 
  Type: spec_store_bypass 
  mitigation: Speculative Store Bypass disabled via prctl and seccomp 
  Type: spectre_v1 
  mitigation: usercopy/swapgs barriers and __user pointer sanitization 
  Type: spectre_v2 mitigation: Full generic retpoline, IBPB: conditional, 
  IBRS_FW, STIBP: conditional, RSB filling 
  Type: srbds mitigation: Microcode 
  Type: tsx_async_abort status: Not affected 
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel UHD Graphics 620 vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: i915 
  v: kernel bus ID: 00:02.0 chip ID: 8086:5917 
  Device-2: NVIDIA GM108M [GeForce 940MX] vendor: Hewlett-Packard 
  driver: nvidia v: 460.32.03 alternate: nouveau,nvidia_drm bus ID: 01:00.0 
  chip ID: 10de:134d 
  Device-3: Chicony HP Wide Vision HD Camera type: USB driver: uvcvideo 
  bus ID: 1-5:4 chip ID: 04f2:b5d6 
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.10 compositor: kwin_x11 driver: 
  loaded: modesetting,nvidia display ID: :0 screens: 1 
  Screen-1: 0 s-res: 1920x1080 s-dpi: 115 s-size: 424x238mm (16.7x9.4") 
  s-diag: 486mm (19.1") 
  Monitor-1: eDP-1 res: 1920x1080 dpi: 158 size: 309x173mm (12.2x6.8") 
  diag: 354mm (13.9") 
  OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel UHD Graphics 620 (KBL GT2) v: 4.6 Mesa 20.3.3 
  direct render: Yes 
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio vendor: Hewlett-Packard 
  driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel alternate: snd_soc_skl bus ID: 00:1f.3 
  chip ID: 8086:9d71 
  Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.10.7-3-MANJARO 
Network:
  Device-1: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet 
  vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: r8168 v: 8.048.03-NAPI modules: r8169 
  port: 3000 bus ID: 02:00.0 chip ID: 10ec:8168 
  IF: eno1 state: down mac: <filter> 
  Device-2: Intel Wireless 7265 driver: iwlwifi v: kernel port: 3000 
  bus ID: 03:00.0 chip ID: 8086:095a 
  IF: wlo1 state: up mac: <filter> 
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 1.03 TiB used: 558.98 GiB (53.2%) 
  SMART Message: Unable to run smartctl. Root privileges required. 
  ID-1: /dev/sda maj-min: 8:0 vendor: Seagate model: ST1000LM035-1RK172 
  size: 931.51 GiB block size: physical: 4096 B logical: 512 B speed: 6.0 Gb/s 
  serial: <filter> rev: RSM7 
  ID-2: /dev/sdb maj-min: 8:16 vendor: SanDisk model: SD8SN8U-128G-1006 
  size: 119.24 GiB block size: physical: 4096 B logical: 512 B speed: 6.0 Gb/s 
  serial: <filter> rev: 0006 
Partition:
  ID-1: / raw size: 50 GiB size: 48.72 GiB (97.43%) used: 38.9 GiB (79.8%) 
  fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sdb5 maj-min: 8:21 
  ID-2: /boot/efi raw size: 277 MiB size: 276.4 MiB (99.80%) 
  used: 280 KiB (0.1%) fs: vfat dev: /dev/sdb1 maj-min: 8:17 
  ID-3: /home raw size: 60.87 GiB size: 59.67 GiB (98.02%) 
  used: 32.17 GiB (53.9%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sdb2 maj-min: 8:18 
Swap:
  Kernel: swappiness: 5 (default 60) cache pressure: 50 (default 100) 
  ID-1: swap-1 type: partition size: 8.1 GiB used: 3.33 GiB (41.1%) 
  priority: -2 dev: /dev/sdb3 maj-min: 8:19 
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 37.5 C mobo: 29.8 C 
  Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A 
Info:
  Processes: 327 Uptime: 1d 21h 20m wakeups: 13 Memory: 7.69 GiB 
  used: 4.69 GiB (61.0%) Init: systemd v: 247 Compilers: gcc: 10.2.0 
  Packages: 1983 pacman: 1976 lib: 457 flatpak: 1 snap: 6 Shell: fish v: 3.1.2 
  running in: server inxi: 3.2.02
```

Comment: "Toggle" is a little ambiguous - is the goal here for your wifi to *not* turn on when your laptop is opened?

Comment: @JamesL By toggle, I meant that it's turned on if it was off, and turned off if it was on. I want it (opening the lid) to not affect the WiFi state in any way.

Comment: I will start with:
1- Tweak some options in  avahi-daemon "/etc/avahi/avahi-daemon.conf". Or
2- Update your BIOS firmware if it is available. Or
3- Install kernel-lts (5.10 has some problems with some bluetooth+wifi cards).
Such glitch used to be with the old gdm.service. If nothing from the 3 have worked for you, then
4- Look at the /sys/power/ 
5 - look for another power management tools

Comment: The above trace looks as if your wifi device gets a new MAC when your lid is opened. Sounds to me rather like a firmware/hardware problem.

Comment: @Nils What can be done?

Comment: @kasa I'll try 5.4 but I really hope that isn't the cause. 5.10 is very snappy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question was solved when I put it on Manjaro Forum. The solution was as follows:

> Make the config file
> `/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/90-disable-randomization.conf` with the
> following content :
>
> ```
> [device-mac-randomization]
> wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
>
> [connection-mac-randomization]
> ## FOR ETHERNET, OPTIONAL IF YOU USE ONLY WLAN
> #ethernet.cloned-mac-address=permanent wifi.cloned-mac-address=permanent
> ```
>
> Then restart NetworkManager.service
>
> `systemctl restart NetworkManager.service`

(Although I had to reboot to make it work.)

Comment: I had this problem too,  on a VM -  and this solved it flawlessly.  I made some minor changes to my setup (the vm) but still - I think nothing else than this made it work;   thanks @MathlsNice1729! this was just brilliant. [+10]

Comment: @WilliamMartens The credit goes to the person on Manjaro Forum. You can thank him [here](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/wifi-is-disconnected-when-lid-is-opened/53407) if you want.

Comment: @MathlsNice1729  Okay, thanks  for pointing it out!  But still.  thanks for spreading his word! //Wishes!